# Compile a C++ program (LANShare)

Tags: c++, c, unix, compilation

I'm having problems compiling LANShare's sourcecode.
I need to compile this program because i need to use it on a 32-bit unix machine and there's no `.deb` or `appimage` release file.

This is [LANShare](https://github.com/abdularis/LAN-Share/tree/master/src).

As you can see there's no config file and i don't know how i can proceed with compilation.
I compiled from source many times but here there's no Readme nor instructions, then I opened an [issue](https://github.com/abdularis/LAN-Share/issues/44) but there's no response yet.

Comment: It looks like there is a [QT project](https://github.com/abdularis/LAN-Share/blob/master/src/LANShare.pro). You need [QT Creator](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/) to use it.

Comment: true, it's specified in the .pro file, i'll do some research on this

Comment: there is a README.md file that tells you everything you need to know, including the location of a deb file

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-tutorial.html

Comment: it works, thanks! I'll add a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, thanks to *n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.*
Theese instructions should be valid for any Debian 10 install.

To install qt tools:

```
sudo apt install qt5-qmake qt5-default
```

then to compile:

```
qmake -o Makefile LANShare.pro
make
```

Answer (score 0):

within the README.md file there is:

You can download the Ubuntu package or linux AppImage or Windows executable from the release page.
https://github.com/abdularis/LAN-Share/releases

- Using .deb (Ubuntu/Debian)

download the latest version, for example `lanshare_1.2.1-1_amd64.deb` then open a terminal, navigate to directory where the downloaded package is located and type

```
$ sudo dpkg -i ./lanshare_1.2.1-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: already tried, doesn't work because of 32-bit architecture